# how to add certain numbers to a list in a python list?

Tags: python, list

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

I want to add `2 and 5`. How do I add up only the numbers 2 and 5 in the list?

I tried this way but getting an error:

```py
x = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
for i in range(len(x)):
    print(sum(x[i][1]))
```

Comment: **How do I add up only the numbers 2 and 5 in the list** you do `x[0][1] + x[1][1]` and you have `2 + 5`

Comment: You mean create a new list with only `2` and `5`. You could be more clear next time.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new variable and assign 0 to it. Then in for loop instead of `print(sum(x[i][1]))` do `my_variable += x[i][1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
new_list = [i[1] for i in x]
```

The result(`new_list`) will be

```
[2, 5]
```

Then you can do whatever you want with your new list.

Answer (score 0):

To use `sum()` function you need multiple elements. Because one element can't iterate.

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
print(sum(i[1] for i in x))

# Output
# 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets understand why you are getting an error. If I remove the `sum()`, you can see that `x[i][1]` returns an integer. This means that when you use `sum(integer)`, it doesn't make sense.

```
x = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
for i in range(len(x)):
    print(x[i][1])

#2
#5
```

You would want to add the 2 numbers to a dummy variable using `+=` to maintain the sum.

```
s = 0
x = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
for i in range(len(x)):
    s+=x[i][1]
print(s)

#7
```

Finally, if you don't want to use `+=` you can always fetch the 2 elements and sum them later. Here I use a list comprehension for this.

```
sum([i[1] for i in x])

#7
```

This is the same as -

```
l = []
x = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
for i in range(len(x)):
    l.append(x[i][1])

print(sum(l))

#7
```